# Is there a way to create a type alias of a std::slice::Iter?

Tags: rust, lifetime, type-alias

I'm trying to create a type alias of a [`Peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html) [`slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html), but the compiler keeps complaining that I need a lifetime parameter.

This iterator is used in several places, and always iterates over the same type. To make the code more concise, I would like to use a type alias.

I have already tried (code examples below):

- Adding a lifetime parameter to the struct it is iterating over, and pass this as the argument to the generic, to no avail.
- Adding a lifetime parameter inside the iterator

```
use std::{iter::Peekable, slice::Iter};

pub struct MyStruct {
    pub arg1: i32,
    pub arg2: i32,
    pub arg3: MyEnum,
}

pub enum MyEnum {
    Default,
}

// mutable since I want to call .peek() and .next() on my iterator
type MyIterator<'a> = &'a mut Peekable<Iter<MyStruct>>;
```

Notice that the above works just fine if I don't use a type alias, i.e. I use it directly in code:

```
pub fn my_fn(it: &mut Peekable<Iter<MyStruct>>) -> i32 { /* ... */ }
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/lib.rs:14:40
   |
14 | type MyIterator<'a> = &'a mut Peekable<Iter<MyStruct>>;
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

I have also tried:

- `...  = &'a Peekable<Iter<&'a MyStruct>>;`
- `...  = &'a Peekable<Iter<MyStruct+ 'a>>;`

Neither work, even when adding a lifetime parameter to the `MyStruct`. I don't really understand how Rust wants me to define the lifetime parameter. (In general I don't fully understand this concept yet as I just started programming in Rust)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are trying to push the reference in the type alias, rather than define the alias as `Peekable<Iter<MyStruct>>` and take a `&mut MyIterator` as a parameter?

Comment: You have not specified which `Iter` you are talking about, there are several types with that name in the standard library (e.g. [`std::slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html)). Nevertheless, note that each of the standard ones have a lifetime parameter, for keeping track of the original data's lifetime.

Comment: @E_net4wisheshappyholidays My bad, I added it to the question.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Oh main reasoning is that it should always be a mutable reference as I want to always call the `next` method. Even when I omit this from the type alias however it complains about a lifetime parameter.

Comment: `Iter` needs a lifetime specified in the alias: `type MyIterator<'a> = Peekable<Iter<'a, MyStruct>>;` At this point I do not think you need to make it a mutable reference.

Comment: Yes true, also found out that I get issues with multiple mutable borrows if I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that Rust is just inferring the lifetime parameter for `Iter` in the function parameter context. But as [E_net4 hinted at in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238520/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-typealias-of-an-iter-in-rust#comment95301997_54238520), the `Iter` you are probably using is defined as `Iter<'a, T: 'a>`. The correct type definition is:

```
type MyIterator<'a> = &'a mut Peekable<Iter<'a, MyStruct>>;
```

Comment: Oh how embarrassing, I looked at the definition of `Peekable` and not `Iter`. It works now, thank you!